# Can't debug on weblogic server : 12.1.3.0.0

Tags: java, debugging, ejb, weblogic

I have this issue in weblogic, version : 12.1.3.0.0. Cannot debug. 
I have been debugging for a long time without any problem.
In my startWebLogic.cmd file I have this options set:

```
SET JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=47871,suspend=n
```

and in Debug Configurations I have created a new remote java application pointing to the ejb project with connection properties set to: 
Host: localhost
Port: 47871

as I have always done before ...

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can u check your port is already occupied or not in your system?

Comment: The port is in status "ESTABILISHED"